# How to convert time in utc second and timezone offset in second to date using java-8?

Tags: java, date, java-8, unix-timestamp, timezone-offset

I have a date in utc second and its time zone offset in sec. I would like to convert it to date string in format yyyy-mm-dd using java8 ZoneOffset class. Below is the time in seconds and offset

```
long time = 1574962442,
long offset = 3600
```

Now i want to obtain date in below format using java-8 DateTime API ?

```
 String date = 2019-11-28 // in yyyy-MM-dd
```

Comment: I recommend this tutorial: [Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)

Comment: There are two fine answers. My preference would for constructing an `OffsetDateTime` as in the answer by Deadpool and then using a formatter for obtaining your string as in the answer by lucid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Instant](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) from java-8 DateTime API to obtains an [OffsetDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) of Instant from epoch seconds with offset seconds

```
OffsetDateTime offsetDateTime = Instant.ofEpochSecond(time)
                                .atOffset(ZoneOffset.ofTotalSeconds(offset));
```

And the get [LocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) from it

```
LocalDate localdate = offsetDateTime.toLocalDate();  //2019-11-28
```

If you want string formatted output use [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)

```
String output = localdate.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE);
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use java 8 `LocalDateTime` APIs to achieve this.

```
LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.ofEpochSecond(1574962442, 0, ZoneOffset.ofTotalSeconds(3600));

// for format
String formatted = dateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"))
```

Comment: Or just `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE`.