# How to extract the period of the day from milliseconds timestamp in Java?

Tags: java

Could somebody please shed some light on how can I get a period of the day (AM/PM) from the milliseconds timestamp value?
This is currently being done by the following code:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(new Date(prevDate));
assertEquals(cal.get(Calendar.AM_PM), Calendar.PM));
```

I just need to get rid of `java.util.Calendar`.

My only idea is to convert `long` value to `LocalDateTime` and then to access `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("a");`.
Perhaps somebody could suggest another approach?

Comment: something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59349957/how-to-convert-time-in-utc-second-and-timezone-offset-in-second-to-date-using-ja/59350023#59350023

Comment: I would try converting to `LocalTime`  and then `get(ChronoField.AMPM_OF_DAY)`

Comment: Another option would be the field `hour` of a `LocalDateTime`, it holds values from `0` to `23`, easy to determine where the change from AM to PM is...

Comment: The suggested duplicate ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59349957/642706)) is *not* a duplicate. This question asks for AM or PM while the other asks about getting the date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned the formatting code, so it's not clear whether you are looking for a (localized?) string representation of AM/PM, but given a `Clock` in the appropriate zone, this will indicate the status:

```
boolean am = LocalTime.now(clock).isBefore(LocalTime.NOON);
```

If you have a specific Unix time as a number of milliseconds since the epoch, you'll need to specify the local time zone or offset in which you are interested to complete the conversion:

```
LocalTime when = Instant.ofEpochMilli(prevDate).atZone(zoneId).toLocalTime();
int meridiem = when.isBefore(LocalTime.NOON) ? Calendar.AM : Calendar.PM;
Assert.assertEquals(meridiem, Calendar.PM);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. This really makes sense to me, but I need to avoid using ```java.util.Calendar```.

Comment: @GlebTereshkov I just left `Calendar` in the test to show that the new code is actually producing equivalent results, so it won’t break any other callers when you ditch calendar. You can replace `Calendar.PM` with 1, define your own constants, or an enum.

Answer (score 1):

## `AmPm` enum

I suggest you add the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) library to your project. This gives you a [`AmPm`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/AmPm.html) class to represent the AM or PM value that you seek. That `AmPm` class is an enum, defining two objects, one for AM and one for PM. The class carries methods, including the [`from`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/AmPm.html#from(java.time.temporal.TemporalAccessor)) method to determine the AM or PM of a given moment.

Using an object here makes your code more [self-documenting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-documenting_code), provides [type-safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety), and ensures valid values.

Note that a time zone is crucial here. For any given moment, the time-of-day (and even the date) varies around the globe by zone. So while a moment may be morning in Tokyo Japan, it may still be evening in Toledo Ohio US.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z );
AmPm amPm = AmPm.from( zdt );
```

You could then proceed to branch on which enum object was obtained.

```
switch ( amPm )
{
    case AM:
        System.out.println( "Good morning." );
        break ;
    case PM:
        System.out.println( "Good day." );
        break ;

    default:
        System.out.println( "ERROR Should never reach this point." );
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed response. Not sure that the usage of an external library would be agreed by others working on my project, but I'll give it a chance.
Extra thanks for highlighting the importance of time zone. Will definitely consider this!

Comment: Don't forget the `break` statements, to avoid fall-through.